# Are Item Finder and Dowsing Machine the same card?

Tags: pokemon

Item Finder is a card from the original Pokemon TCG Base Set. Dowsing Machine is a card that has the same effect, but was printed as an Ace Spec in the much more recent Plasma Storm set.

I would like to a build a deck for the Unlimited format that includes 4 Item Finder and also includes 1 Dowsing Machine as my Ace Spec card.

I have read that the original Japanese names for the cards Item Finder and Dowsing Machine are the same. Does this mean that they are supposed to be treated as the same card for deck building purposes?

I have found some discussions online that assumed one way or the other, but I haven't found any source that seemed authoritative. I know that in the Pokemon TCG a card is supposed to be played using the text of its most recent printing, but I don't know if these two cards count as the same to apply that ruling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no official source saying they are the same card, even though they have the same effect, you should be fine playing with 4 and 1 in Unlimited. There's no reason to assume the rules are different than any other two cards, if this were a special case it would be outlined somewhere.